# Android Cloud Storage

Tags: android, backup, cloud

I understand that this is an **insanely** broad topic, but can anyone give me any starting links/documentation on how to integrate cloud storage into my app? As an example (this isn't the actual app, since there's dozens of apps like this), I want the user to write a note and have it automatically saved to some cloud linked to their specific account. Now, I'm aware that I could work with DropBox to achieve this, but that requires the user to have a DropBox account and I would like this to work independently of any third-party services.

I know this is a lot to ask, but are there any beginner resources out there that anyone can think of to get me started thinking about this?

Thanks!

EDIT: For all those downvoting, I understand that this is a broad topic. I just wanted to throw the question out there to the developer community and see if there were any favorite resources people used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point for this is the Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) introduced in Android 2.2. You should play around with it a little bit. It will give you a first understanding of what a cloud service is all about and what it entails on the server side as well as the client side. Take at the blod post, [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html).